# Web Deploy to multiple servers at once from within Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-web-deploy

What is the easiest way to deploy to multiple servers with as few clicks as possible from within Visual Studio? We are using web deploy, not FTP or file system if that is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure that's possible from within Visual Studio.

Take a look at this article. It describes doing it via the commandline, which might be useful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731049.aspx